# understanding variable scope with FOR vs IF loop

Tags: javascript

My goal was to create a function for a click event that would count up on each click, and use that counter as an array index in order to increment through an array. Can someone help me understand why the first code block produced the desired result, but the second does not. I have a feeling it has to do with variable scope, but this is my first JavaScript project. Thank you.

```
var i = 0;

function click(){
if(i < Questions.length-1){
            i++;
            div.innerHTML = Questions[i].question;
        }
    }
```

Does not produce them saves results as this code:

```
function click(){
   for(var i = 0; i < Questions.length-1; i++){
        div.innerHTML = Questions[i].question;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first one you have a global `i`.

This means:

1. If anything else uses `i` it will clobber the value used in `click`, and
2. After you call `click` the first time you're using the value of `i` as set by the last call of `click`, or whatever modified it outside of `click`.

In the second one you have an `i` local *only* to the `click` function. It's initialized, used, and discarded when the method completes.

You set the `innerHTML` to *all* the questions, and the last one set will be the one you see.

Even though the first one *works* (at the moment) having a global variable named `i` is pretty risky, and brittle. You'd be better off encapsulating the question index.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with the scope.

The first method is correct because, on each click `i` is incremented once, and the `i`th question is displayed.

In the second method, on every click you're iterating through all the questions in one go. Hence, in the end only the last question would be printed in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays begin at index 0, so you need to access the array before incrementing your counter. For instance, your first code should look like :

```
var i = 0;

function click(){
    if (i <= Questions.length-1) {
        div.innerHTML = Questions[i].question;
        i++;
    }
}
```

or even better (more concise) :

```
var i = 0;

function click(){
    if (i <= Questions.length-1) {
        div.innerHTML = Questions[i++].question;
    }
}
```

Note the `<=` instead of `=` because if your have a 2-sized array, index 1 is good (and the last entry, actually).

Your second code iterates over the whole array at each click (an then displays only the before-last question in array) whereas the first code only increment when the element is clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interpretation. Not sure if that is what you're looking for.
The code block has nothing special to do with javascript.

The first block simply increment i once and the second loops through it until array ends.

Here are some excerpts from my Chrome console:

```
var i=0;
function callMe(){
if (i < arr.length-1){
i++;
console.log(arr[i]);
}
}

arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

function callMe2(){
for (var j=0; j < arr.length; j++){
console.log(arr[j]);
}
}
```

And then..

```
callMe()
two 

callMe()
three 

callMe()
four 

callMe()
<blank>

callMe2()
one
two
three
four
```

Hope this helps!